# How do I change values in a dataframe that is below the threshold value of the sample?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of 300 rows and 63 columns (representing the different samples). I want to use a threshold of 5% to discard any values that fall below that.

Here is the code that I have:

```
thresholdForRemoval <- function(x){
  quantile(x[x> 0], probs = 0.05)
}
thresholds <- apply(df, MARGIN = 2, FUN = thresholdForRemoval)
x <- df
y <- thresholds

for(i in 1:ncol(x)){
  x[,i] <- ifelse(x[,i] < y[i], 0, x[,i])
}
```

Here is the error that I am running into:
Error in `vectbl_as_new_col_index()`:
! Can't recycle `ifelse(x[, i] < y[i], 0, x[, i])` (size 300) to size 1.

What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you clarify your question by making a reproducible example? The code you added provides very little opportunity to help without the underlying data. Try pasting the output of `dput(df)`

Comment: also the criterion for discarding data isn't clear.  From your code it looks like you want to set the lowest 5% non-zero observations (calculated within each column) to zero?

Comment: @George Yeap, that is correct.

Comment: @jpsmith I realised I couldn't create a reproducible example which hints to me that the problem is with my dataset. Thank you!

Comment: Why cant you create a reproducible example?